# How to import a file in a folder into a file in another folder in rust?

Tags: import, module, rust, rust-crates

```
src
 I -- handlers
         I--- authhandler.rs
      models
         I--- account.rs
         I--- mod.rs
```

authhandler:

```
pub fn register(register: web::Json<RegisterRequest>) -> impl Responder {
   .........
}
```

account:

```
pub struct RegisterRequest {
    email: String,
    password: String
}
```

mod.rs

```
pub mod account;
```

I have tried to use `use models::account::RegisterRequest;`and `crate models::account::RegisterRequest` None of this worked out.

How can import RegisterRequest into authhandler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out that the `RegisterRequest` missed the `use` keyword and can be imported as:

```
use crate::models::account::RegisterRequest;
```